# Weblogic Server Exception: weblogic.management.DeploymentException

Tags: oracle, soa, weblogic11g

**I got this error while trying to deploy the services used by the Store Front module to send orders to theOrderBookingComposite composite. According to the tutorial:**

a. In the Application Navigator, right click StoreFrontModule and choose
Deploy > StoreFrontModule_SDOServices > to > MyAppServerConnection.
You created this connection in Section 1.2.4, "Task 4: Create a Connection to an
Oracle WebLogic Server."

b. In the Select Deployment Targets dialog, select the Managed Server for the
Oracle WebLogic Server, such as soa_server, and click OK

c. In the Deployment Configuration dialog, accept the default MDS repository
name and partition name, and then click Deploy.

**Here is log:**

```
[12:35:55 PM] ----  Deployment started.  ----
[12:35:55 PM] Target platform is  (Weblogic 10.3).
[12:35:56 PM] Retrieving existing application information
[12:35:56 PM] Running dependency analysis...
[12:35:56 PM] Building...
[12:35:57 PM] Deploying 4 profiles...
[12:35:57 PM] Wrote MAR file to D:\DOWNLOADS\SOA 11gR1\FusionOrderDemo_R1PS4\StoreFrontModule\deploy\AutoGeneratedMar.mar
[12:35:58 PM] Wrote EJB Module to D:\DOWNLOADS\SOA 11gR1\FusionOrderDemo_R1PS4\StoreFrontModule\StoreFrontService\deploy\StoreFrontServiceHooks.jar
[12:35:58 PM] Wrote Archive Module to D:\DOWNLOADS\SOA 11gR1\FusionOrderDemo_R1PS4\StoreFrontModule\StoreFrontService\deploy\SDOServices_Common.jar
[12:35:58 PM] Uploading jazn-data users.
[12:35:58 PM] Updating user "sking".
[12:35:58 PM] Updating user "ahunold".
[12:35:58 PM] Updating user "fdaviet".
[12:35:58 PM] Updating user "ngreenbe".
[12:35:58 PM] Updating user "pbrown".
[12:35:58 PM] Uploading jazn-data roles.
[12:35:58 PM] Removing existing group "fod-users".
[12:35:58 PM] Creating group for role "fod-users".
[12:35:58 PM] Removing existing group "fod-admin".
[12:35:58 PM] Creating group for role "fod-admin".
[12:35:58 PM] Adding "sking" to group "fod-users".
[12:35:58 PM] Adding "ahunold" to group "fod-users".
[12:35:58 PM] Adding "fdaviet" to group "fod-users".
[12:35:58 PM] Adding "ngreenbe" to group "fod-users".
[12:35:58 PM] Adding "pbrown" to group "fod-users".
[12:35:58 PM] Adding "sking" to group "fod-admin".
[12:35:58 PM] Adding "ahunold" to group "fod-admin".
[12:35:58 PM] Wrote Enterprise Application Module to D:\DOWNLOADS\SOA 11gR1\FusionOrderDemo_R1PS4\StoreFrontModule\deploy\StoreFrontService_SDOServices.ear
[12:35:58 PM] D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\jdk160_24\jre\bin\java.exe -client -jar D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\jdeveloper\..\oracle_common\modules\oracle.webservices_11.1.1\wsa.jar -jaxwsEjbAssemble -input /D:/DOWNLOADS/SOA 11gR1/FusionOrderDemo_R1PS4/StoreFrontModule/deploy/StoreFrontService_SDOServices.ear -output D:\DOWNLOADS\SOA 11gR1\FusionOrderDemo_R1PS4\StoreFrontModule\deploy\tmp -classpath D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.adf.share_11.1.1\adf-share-support.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.adf.share.ca_11.1.1\adf-share-ca.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.adf.share.ca_11.1.1\adf-share-base.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.adf.share_11.1.1\adflogginghandler.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.adf.share_11.1.1\adfsharembean.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jmx_11.1.1\jmxframework.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jmx_11.1.1\jmxspi.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.idm_11.1.1\identitystore.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.adf.model_11.1.1\adfm.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.adf.model_11.1.1\bc4j-mbeans.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.adf.model_11.1.1\bc4jwizard.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\groovy-all-1.6.3.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.xdk_11.1.0\xmlparserv2.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.adf.model_11.1.1\db-ca.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.adf.model_11.1.1\jdev-cm.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.ldap_11.1.1\ojmisc.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.adf.share_11.1.1\commons-el.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.adf.share_11.1.1\jsp-el-api.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.adf.share_11.1.1\oracle-el.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.javatools_11.1.1\resourcebundle.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\modules\javax.activation_1.1.0.0_1-1.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\modules\javax.mail_1.1.0.0_1-4-1.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.adf.model_11.1.1\adftransactionsdt.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.adf.view_11.1.1\adf-dt-at-rt.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.adf.model_11.1.1\adfdt_common.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.adf.model_11.1.1\adflibrary.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.adf.security_11.1.1\adf-share-security.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.adf.security_11.1.1\adf-controller-security.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jdbc_11.1.1\ojdbc6dms.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\jdeveloper\BC4J\jlib\bc4jtester.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jps_11.1.1\jps-api.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.adf.model_11.1.1\adfm-debugger.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.adf.model_11.1.1\regexp.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.help_5.0\ohj.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.help_5.0\help-share.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.bali.share_11.1.1\share.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\jdeveloper\jlib\jewt4.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.help_5.0\oracle_ice.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\jdeveloper\ide\lib\idert.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\jdeveloper\ide\lib\javatools.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.mds_11.1.1\mdsrt.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\jdeveloper\ide\macros\..\..\..\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\ojdbc6.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\jdeveloper\ide\macros\..\..\..\oracle_common\modules\oracle.nlsrtl_11.1.0\orai18n.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.odl_11.1.1\ojdl.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.dms_11.1.1\dms.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.adf.model_11.1.1\adfbcsvc.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.adf.model_11.1.1\adfbcsvc-share.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\commonj.sdo_2.1.0.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\modules\org.eclipse.persistence_1.1.0.0_2-1.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.webservices_11.1.1\wsclient.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.web-common_11.1.1.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.ldap_11.1.1\ldapjclnt11.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jps_11.1.1\jps-common.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jps_11.1.1\jps-ee.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jps_11.1.1\jps-internal.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jps_11.1.1\jps-unsupported-api.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jps_11.1.1\jps-manifest.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jps_11.1.1\jacc-spi.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.pki_11.1.1\oraclepki.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.osdt_11.1.1\osdt_core.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.osdt_11.1.1\osdt_cert.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.osdt_11.1.1\osdt_xmlsec.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.osdt_11.1.1\osdt_ws_sx.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.iau_11.1.1\fmw_audit.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\modules\javax.security.jacc_1.0.0.0_1-1.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.mds_11.1.1\oramds.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\modules\javax.servlet_1.0.0.0_2-5.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\modules\javax.jsp_1.2.0.0_2-1.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\jlib\commons-cli-1.0.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.xmlef_11.1.1\xmlef.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.xdk_11.1.0\xml.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.javacache_11.1.1\cache.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.ucp_11.1.0.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.javatools_11.1.1\javatools-nodeps.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\modules\javax.management_1.2.1.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\modules\javax.management.j2ee_1.0.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\oracle_common\modules\oracle.adf.model_11.1.1\adfmweb.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\modules\javax.jsf_1.1.0.0_1-2.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\modules\javax.ejb_3.0.1.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\modules\javax.enterprise.deploy_1.2.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\modules\javax.interceptor_1.0.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\modules\javax.jms_1.1.1.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\modules\javax.jws_2.0.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\modules\javax.xml.soap_1.3.1.0.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\modules\javax.xml.rpc_1.2.1.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\modules\javax.xml.ws_2.1.1.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\modules\javax.resource_1.5.1.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\modules\javax.transaction_1.0.0.0_1-1.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\modules\javax.xml.stream_1.1.1.0.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\modules\javax.xml.registry_1.0.0.0_1-0.jar;D:\Middleware\JDev11gR1PS4\modules\javax.persistence_1.0.0.0_1-0-2.jar -createSchemaMappings -ear /D:/DOWNLOADS/SOA 11gR1/FusionOrderDemo_R1PS4/StoreFrontModule/deploy/StoreFrontService_SDOServices.ear -servletFilterClass oracle.jbo.server.svc.ServiceContextFilter
[12:35:59 PM] INFO: Unable to load annotation weblogic.javaee.CallByReference for parsing.  The annotation is ignored.
[12:35:59 PM] INFO: Unable to load annotation javax.interceptor.Interceptors for parsing.  The annotation is ignored.
[12:35:59 PM] INFO: Unable to load annotation weblogic.javaee.CallByReference for parsing.  The annotation is ignored.
[12:35:59 PM] INFO: Unable to load annotation javax.interceptor.Interceptors for parsing.  The annotation is ignored.
[12:35:59 PM] INFO: GenericWSWarAnnotationListener.parseAnnotatedClass Adding Servlet Mapping with URL pattern /StoreFrontService for annotated WebService class  oracle.fodemo.storefront.store.service.server.serviceinterface.StoreFrontServiceImpl
[12:35:59 PM] WSA process exited with code 0.
[12:35:59 PM] Entering Oracle Deployment Plan Editor
[12:36:03 PM] Deploying Application...
[12:36:04 PM] [Deployer:149191]Operation 'deploy' on application 'StoreFrontService_SDOServices [Version=V2.0]' is initializing on 'soa_server1'
[12:36:04 PM] [Deployer:149193]Operation 'deploy' on application 'StoreFrontService_SDOServices [Version=V2.0]' has failed on 'soa_server1'
[12:36:04 PM] [Deployer:149034]An exception occurred for task [Deployer:149026]deploy application StoreFrontService_SDOServices [Version=V2.0] on soa_server1.: [J2EE:160149]Error while processing library references. Unresolved application library references, defined in weblogic-application.xml: [Extension-Name: adf.oracle.domain, exact-match: false]..
[12:36:04 PM] Weblogic Server Exception: weblogic.management.DeploymentException: [J2EE:160149]Error while processing library references. Unresolved application library references, defined in weblogic-application.xml: [Extension-Name: adf.oracle.domain, exact-match: false].
[12:36:04 PM]   See server logs or server console for more details.
[12:36:04 PM] weblogic.management.DeploymentException: [J2EE:160149]Error while processing library references. Unresolved application library references, defined in weblogic-application.xml: [Extension-Name: adf.oracle.domain, exact-match: false].
[12:36:04 PM] ####  Deployment incomplete.  ####
[12:36:04 PM] Remote deployment failed (oracle.jdevimpl.deploy.common.Jsr88RemoteDeployer)
```

**And here content of build.properties file**

```
####################################################################
#       Global build property set for SOA fusion order demo        #
# > author: clemens utschig (oracle corp) 2009                     #
####################################################################

# path for libraries and script imports
# oracle.home=C:\\JDeveloper\\11.1.1.3\\jdeveloper\\
oracle.home=D:/Middleware/JDev11gR1PS4/jdeveloper
################ INTERNAL SEED PROPERTIES - BEGIN ##################
#                                                                  #
#                   !!!!! DO NOT MODIFY !!!!!                      #
#                                                                  #
####################################################################

# internal version number
fod.version=2.3_ps3

# common libs home 
oracle.common.home=${oracle.home}/../oracle_common

# Sub directory for deployment artifacts
deploy.sub.dir=deploy
# sub directory for deployment / build scripts 
bin.sub.dir=bin

# jee application homes
creditauthorization.home=../CreditCardAuthorization
orderapproval.home=../OrderApprovalHumanTask
external.partnersupplier.home=../ExternalLegacyPartnerSupplierEjb
# composite homes
orderbookingsdo.composite.home=../OrderSDOComposite
partnersupplier.composite.home=../PartnerSupplierComposite
orderbooking.composite.home=../OrderBookingComposite
b2b.composite.home=../B2BX12OrderGateway

# adf service implementation context url
storefrontservice.contextUri.adf=StoreFrontServiceHooks/StoreFrontService
# sca composite based context url
storefrontservice.contextUri.soa=soa-infra/services/${soa.partition.name}/OrderSDOComposite!1.0/StoreFrontService

# ejb uri for the ExternalPartnerSupplierEJB
partnersupplier.ejb.uri=WebLogicFusionOrderDemo-ExternalLegacyPartnerSupplierEjb-SessionEJB#com.otn.sample.fod.soa.externalps.IExternalPartnerSupplierService
# ejb uri for the ExternalPartnerSupplierEJB JSca implementation via Spring C&I
partnersupplier.jsca.ejb.uri=WebLogicFusionOrderDemo-ExternalLegacyPartnerSupplierJScaEjb

## global connection settings for deployer, rmi and others

# admin server t3:// url - for deployment
wls.url=t3://${admin.server.host}:${admin.server.port}
# mgd server t3:// url - for ejb
wls.mgd.server.url=t3://${managed.server.host}:${managed.server.rmi.port}
# the jndi ctx factory
java.naming.factory.initial=weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory

################## INTERNAL SEED PROPERTIES - END ####################

# partition where the composites should be deployed to
soa.partition.name=soaFusionOrderDemo

# set to false if you want to use adf backed services.
soa.only.deployment=false

# deploy the b2b x12 order processing composite
enable.b2b.composite=true

# use a normal ejb3 for the external partner supplier (comment or set to false), 
# or use the new Weblogic SCA for Java EJB binding (uncomment and set to true)
use.jsca.ejb.impl=true

# file adapter directory - amend to your OS (use \\ for windows and / for unix)
orderbooking.file.adapter.dir=/tmp

# file adapter control directory - amend to your OS (use \\ for windows and / for unix)
orderbooking.file.adapter.control.dir=/tmp/control

# jndi name of the jms topic for orderbooking composite
orderbooking.jms.topic.jndi=jms/DemoSupplierTopicUdd

###### Deployment server connection information 

# the admin server connection information - to seed the topics
admin.server.host=localhost
admin.server.port=7001

# the domain where soa infra is installed
# server.domain.name=soainfra
server.domain.name=SOAOSBPS4DevDomain
# connection information for the managed server, used for soa-deployment, http
managed.server.host=localhost
managed.server.port=8001

# rmi port for testing, ejb invocation and others
managed.server.rmi.port=8001


# credential information for the servers
server.user=weblogic
server.password=welcome1

# wls target server (for shiphome set to server_soa, for ADRS use AdminServer)
server.targets=soa_server1
#server.targets=AdminServer

# soa-server side oracle home directory - needed for deployment plans
# and the weblogic sca library deployment (out of the ExternalPartnerSupplier project
# soa.server.oracle.home=/scratch/cutschig/fmwhome/AS11gR1SOA
# soa.server.oracle.home=c:/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3
soa.server.oracle.home= D:/Middleware/JDev11gR1PS4/wlserver_10.3

####### for business event testing - this is to enqueue the business event 

# soa db main schema username 
# soa.db.username=cutschig_soainfra
soa.db.username=dev_soainfra
# soa db password
# soa.db.password=soainfra
soa.db.password=welcome1

# soa db connect string => host:port:sid
soa.db.connectstring=localhost:1521:xe

##### MetaDataServices repository settings (used for SOA shared artifacts) #####

# use "jdev" for local jdeveloper install, "db" for database
# In case of "db" amend the below (jdbc) settings for the mds db

foreign.mds.type=db

# Note: BEFORE you deploy make sure you amend these settings to your REMOTE 
# db - that is backing soa-infra, set the above mds.type to "db" and run 
# the "importCommonServiceArtifactsIntoMds" target. This will import the common
# shared artifacts of $OH/bin/soa-seed/ into the remote (RT) mds. 
# On a shiphome install this user is normally named sh_mds

#mds.db.userid=cutschig_mds
mds.db.userid=dev_mds
#mds.db.password=soainfra
mds.db.password=welcome1

# database connection string: driver@host:port:sid
mds.db.jdbc-url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
```

**Any ideas how to resolve this error?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meanwhile, thankfully to [this](http://satishvchandran.blogspot.com/2013/07/deploymentexception-j2ee160149error.html) blog, I found correct answer, although I did it through Oracle Administrative Console instead of editing config.xml directly. It is not necessary to restart managed server at all.

[image]

[image]

[image]